# How can I disable authorization in SoapUI?

Tags: soapui

I'm testing my WS with and without authorization (turning it on and off and restarting). I spent a lot of time wondering why it is connecting to WS with security even when I provided *No Authorization*:

[image: SoapUI No Authorization screenshot]

In between I tested the same with curl, later on I checked and realized, that in my request, there is still *Authorization* header even when I selected *No Authorization* option.

In *Raw* tab I can see:

[image: SoapUI, Raw tab screenshot]

How can I choose *No Authorization* properly?

My version is SoapUI 5.4.0-EB

**edit 1:** As a workaround (to test my service is or is not password protected) I'm setting correct/incorrect credentials. In short if I send incorrect credentials to service without password it should pass, with password set it should fail.

Comment: Have you got chance to try soluton?

Comment: I've experienced the same issue. Seems to happen when there are already other basic auth protected resources in the same project.

Answer (score 1):

Sending the authentication to outgoing requests be controlled thru Preferences.

Go to menu

```
File -> Preferences -> HTTP Settings -> Authenticate Preemptively
```

and uncheck `Authenticate Preemptively` and Save preferences. More details can be found [here](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/soapui-interface/preferences-and-settings.html) from documentation.

Now, authentication details are not sent in the requests.

If you want again to send the authentication, restore the the above change.

Comment: Hi Rao, nice try, but it is not working for me. `Authenticate Preemptively` was already unchecked. My understanding of preemtive authentication is, it will send credentials before server asks for it. My issue is, that SoapUI sends some cached credentials even when I configured "No Authorization".

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the username and password properties in the request properties TAB.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add an Authorization header with no value.

This will overwrite the default Authorization header SoapUi seems to adds when authorization is set to "No Authorization"

[image: Empty Authorization header]